# What is Rotation when pose is looking back?

Tags: cameras, visual-odometry

[image]

I've model a relative pose between two cameras. $T_0$ is origin and $T_1$ has the relative pose.

The $Camera_0$ is facing a the map point $X$, and I can get a vector $v_0$ from $Camera_0$ toward $X$.

How to determine the rotation matrix of $Camera_2$, which facing direct back? following a $-v_0$

Thanks.

Comment: Is it not just the inverse of the rotation matrix? And the inverse of a rotation matrix should be its transpose, too, I believe.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2895880/inversion-of-rotation-matrix/2895897#2895897

Comment: $R_0$ is identify matrix, its inverse would be also identify. This is what I can't figure out.